# Binding dataset to dynamic generated textbox in loop

Tags: vb.net, textbox, dataset

I'm unable to get the dynamically generated textboxes display the right data when binding it to a dataset.

The dataset holds 2 tables. The `Environments` table has 4 rows with the values `DEV`, `TST`, `ACC`, `PROD`.

```
Dim cma As CurrencyManager
cma = CType(BindingContext(oConfData.dsJimConfig.Tables("Environments")), CurrencyManager)

For i As Integer = 0 To intNrEnvCombi - 1
   cma.Position = i

   Dim txt As TextBox = New TextBox
   With txt
      .Margin = New Padding(5)
      .TabIndex = intTabIdx
      .Name = arrLabelText(3) & i
         If i > cma.Count - 1 Then
          .Text = ""
        Else
          .DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", oConfData.dsJimConfig.Tables("Environments"), "Environment"))
        End If
      .CausesValidation = True
    AddHandler txt.Validating, AddressOf Text_Validating
    AddHandler txt.GotFocus, AddressOf Text_setClear
    AddHandler txt.Leave, AddressOf Text_Format
  End With
Next
```

In all textboxes, data from the last record is shown `PROD`.

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind a `Control` to a specific element of your data source (and not the entire collection), you can make use of a [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(v=vs.110).aspx) and set its [`Position` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.position(v=vs.110).aspx) to the index of the element you want to bind to.

---

Consider this simple example:

```
Dim table = New DataTable()
table.Columns.Add("FooBar")
table.Rows.Add({"First"})
table.Rows.Add({"Second"})
table.Rows.Add({"Third"})

Dim panel = new FlowLayoutPanel()
For i = 0 To 2 
    Dim bs = new BindingSource With
    {
        .DataSource = table,
        .Position = i
    }

    Dim box = new TextBox
    box.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bs, "FooBar"))
    panel.Controls.Add(box)
Next

Dim f = new Form()
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
f.Controls.Add(panel)
f.ShowDialog()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thx so much! Changed the databinding for updating the DS. .DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bsEnv, "Environment", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))